# How to refactor a AutoMapper function in Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm resolving a Software Developer entrance exam where I have to develop a Student Enroll courses app, and in one of the stages wherein it requires to write a Mapper function that map a Model with his ModelDto. I did this, but now I have to refactor in order with the Omnio(clean architecture) methodology software development.

This is the Subject model:

```
  public class Subject
    {
        public int? SubjectId {get; set; }
        public string? Title {get; set; }
        public int? Credits {get; set; }
        public string registerAt? {get; set;}
   }
```

public class SubjectDto

```
 public string? Title {get; set; }
 public int? Credits {get; set; }
 public string registerAt? {get; set;}
```

Now this is the Mapper config I settle down:

```
public class MapperConfig:Profile
        {
            public static MapperConfiguration InitializeAutoMapper()
            {
                //Provide all the Mapping Configuration
                var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    //Configuring Subject and EmployeeDTO
                    cfg.CreateMap<Subject, SubjectDto>()
                    //Provide Mapping Configuration of FullName and Name Property
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Title, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.Title))
                    
                    //Provide Mapping Dept of FullName and Department Property
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Credits, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.Credits));
                    //Any Other Mapping Configuration ....
                });
                return config;
            }
        }
```

And this is how I used it in controller:

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<SubjectDto>> GetAllAsync(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
          var subjects = await _context.Subject.GetSubjectsAsync(id, cancellationToken);
          
          if (subjects is null)
          {
             throw new SubjectNotFoundException(id);
          }

          var mapper = MapperConfig.InitializeAutoMapper();

          var subjectDto = mapper.Map<SubjectDto>(subjects); #cause the error CS1061     
        }
```

It return me that MapperConfig doesnt have a extensible method for Map.

If anyone could help to correctly refactor the Mapper function, I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your configuration class:

```
public class MapperConfig
{
    public static Mapper InitializeAutoMapper()
    {
        //Provide all the Mapping Configuration
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            //Configuring Subject and EmployeeDTO
            cfg.CreateMap<Subject, SubjectDto>()
            //Provide Mapping Configuration of FullName and Name Property
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Title, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.Title))

            //Provide Mapping Dept of FullName and Department Property
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Credits, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.Credits));
            //Any Other Mapping Configuration ....
        });

        var mapper = new Mapper(config);

        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to correct your models:

```
public string registerAt? {get; set;}
```

to

```
public string? registerAt {get; set;}
```

and finally, in your case, make the map for the list you are returning:

```
 var subjects = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SubjectDto>>(subjects)
 retunr subjects ;
```

I hope I was helpfull